# Can ‘went to see’ be changed into ‘ went and see’?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

We went to see a film.

We went and see a film.

We went and saw a film.

Is the second sentence right or the third?

Answer (score 1):

We went to see a film may not tell whether  you  saw  the  film or  not.It only says  that only you went but you might or might not have seen the  film.

> **We went and  saw a film**  is  the correct sentence
>
> **We went and  see a film** is  wrong because of the sequence of tense .